# How can I read an array value saved in a data file stored inside Config folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, config

I need to read special configuration for my app in Laravel 8, all my settings are stored in a single filename naned mydata.php inside folder/config

inside mydata.php

```
return [
    'setting1' => 99,
];
```

I have tried to read it using

```
dd(config('mydata.setting1'));
```

but always return null, I need to get setting1 value

so, I have cleared all config cached

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dumpautoload
```

but It always returns null

thanks

Comment: I would assume that PHP file starts with `<?php` ?   and `config('mydata')` returns `null` as well?

Comment: yes, it returned null too, I have to restart and now it works... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// config/app.php
<?php

return [
    'key' => 'value',
];
```

and access like

```
config('app.key');
```

this is the standard. Is that your actual code up there? Maybe your config file is referring to an env variable that you have not set correctly? It would be easier to help if you would show us your code

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, your statement works very good... but I want to keep my data in a different file mydata.php... so I tried config('mydata.key') and always return null

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know what was wrong but after restart and I get the correct value

```
dd(config('mydata'));
```